# Setting write break point on a variable in a structure dynamically allocated in C

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, breakpoints

I have defined a structure and it gets allocated at runtime. I want to set a breakpoint on it when its value is changed.
I have seen answers, but they don't take into consideration of dynamically allocated variables.

Watch in gdb. I tried looking for it dynamically but found on predefined variables, memory can be found out via gdb and then setting a check on that memory address.

Comment: `watch` also works for allocated memory.

Comment: Try `watch -l expression`.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI How do you use `watch -l`?

Comment: @AllanWind You would use it on an expression that already has an address (i.e. `watch -l foo->bar` only after the call to `malloc`). This will watch an appropriately sized memory location at that address.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI  `watch foo->bar` works even before so what's the point of `-l`?  I read the manual and experimented but didn't bring me any clarity.

Comment: @AllanWind `watch foo->bar` watches the expression. If `foo` changes to point at some other object, then that object's `bar` will be watched. OTOH `watch -l` watches a fixed location.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious so here an example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo {
    int bar;
};

int main() {
    struct foo *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);
    foo->bar = 42;
    printf("bar=%d\n", foo->bar);
    foo->bar = 1;
    printf("bar=%d\n", foo->bar);
    free(foo);
}
```

and a gdb session using watch:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1161: file 1.c, line 9.
Starting program: /home/allan/a.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at 1.c:9
9               struct foo *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);
(gdb) watch foo->bar
Hardware watchpoint 2: foo->bar
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: foo->bar

Old value = -134434816
New value = 0
main () at 1.c:10
10              foo->bar = 42;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: foo->bar

Old value = 0
New value = 42
main () at 1.c:11
11              printf("bar=%d\n", foo->bar);
(gdb) c
Continuing.
bar=42

Hardware watchpoint 2: foo->bar

Old value = 42
New value = 1
main () at 1.c:13
13              printf("bar=%d\n", foo->bar);
(gdb) c
Continuing.
bar=1

Hardware watchpoint 2: foo->bar

Old value = 1
New value = 1431655769
```

Comment: Why would it get set to zero? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lundin I noticed that, too, and don't have an answer as to why (it's malloc not calloc).

Comment: gcc may with optimization enabled remove the entire malloc/free and just store data in a local register. I can make it do that, but I can't make it set the cell to zero... some sort of gdb hiccup?

Comment: Check out this: https://godbolt.org/z/hY9h4nEoj. With optimization on, the value gets stored in a register and malloc is never called. However, if I print the contents returned from malloc - supposedly an indeterminate value - then the program does call malloc and it also prints zero. So it's some quirk in the C lib or maybe in the Linux brk/sbrk. The internals of dynamic allocation in Linux is... special snowflake land. I can't reproduce it with gcc/mingw in Windows.

Comment: New pages of memory allocated by the kernel are zero initialised.  So the first allocations in your application are likely (but not guaranteed) to land in "fresh" (i.e. zero filled) memory.  The malloc does not zero initialised means that when you free memory and return it to libc, there is no requirement to clear that memory before handing it back out again.

Comment: @Lundin Debugging with `-O3` is a bad idea. The compiler optimized a lot of things away. Use `-Og` instead.

Comment: If that answered your question please accept it by clicking the check mark next to it.